# Does cleaning camps count towards "enemies-killed" stacks?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Example: [Raynor - Seasoned Marksman](http://heroesofthestorm.gamepedia.com/Raynor#Talents)

> For every 6 enemy Minion or Mercenary kills near your Hero, gain 1 Basic Attack damage. Hero Takedowns count as 2 Minion kills.

What is meant by Mercenary kill?

1. When you kill an enemy teams Mercenary?
2. When you kill Mercenaries in the jungle? (technically you don't kill them)
3. Both

Comment: When you defeat a merc it counts as 1, the siege camp has 2 guys, it counts as 2 kills

Answer (score 4):

Based on personal experience I would say both. Remember that kills do not mean directly killing a mercenary/minion, it is enough if they die near you.

Comment: I'd say both too.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them count as you can see `+xp` when they die, either in neutral form or as enemy mercs.

Comment: so buildings count too? they give + XP .... i don't think thats a good indicator

Comment: What a solid reasoning you got there. I thought the tooltip was clear enough: 'For every 6 enemy **Minion or Mercenary**...' Since we are speaking of mercenaries and how minion kills are attributed to players, the answer is clear enough with the given context. What do you think is a good indicator then?

Comment: if you KILL an enemy mercenary it counts. i know that. but when you capture them, you don't really kill them (they are still alive)

Comment: Well, I have say that they 'sort of' die before you capture them. Maybe giants surrender and kneel but knights clearly play their death animation. Either killing enemy ones or killing neutral ones before capture count towards marksman.